# php - array - Illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to display single value from array of values.
If I use `print_r($arr)` it shows this values

```
{
    "a": 14,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 61200,
    "d": [
        "2014-04-22 12:00:06",
        "2014-04-23 12:00:06",
        "2014-04-24 12:00:06"
    ]
}
```

But when I tried to use `echo $arr->a` and `$arr['a']`.
It shows `illegal string offset 'a'`.
How to get single value from array of values?

Comment: decode it to an array first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like json so need decode first with [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$d = '{"a":14,"b":3,"c":61200,"d":["2014-04-22 12:00:06","2014-04-23 12:00:06","2014-04-24 12:00:06"]}';
$j = json_decode($d);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($j);
echo $j->a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$arr = json_decode($arr);
echo $arr->a
```

Answer (score 1):

Decode from JSON:

```
$v = json_decode('{
    "a": 14,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 61200,
    "d": [
        "2014-04-22 12:00:06",
        "2014-04-23 12:00:06",
        "2014-04-24 12:00:06"
    ]
}');

echo $v->a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The input looks like JSON - try the following to parse the JSON data:

```
$json_string = '{
    "a": 14,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 61200,
    "d": [
        "2014-04-22 12:00:06",
        "2014-04-23 12:00:06",
        "2014-04-24 12:00:06"
    ]
}';

$vals = json_decode($json_string);

echo $vals->a;
```

Answer (score 1):

More information would be useful. What version of PHP are using? Are you using a web engine (Apache, Nginx, etc) or just command line? Correct me if I'm wrong but I am assuming your using json_decode and making an it an object.

```
$obj = json_decode('{"a":14,"b":3,"c":61200,"d":["2014-04-22 12:00:06","2014-04-23 12:00:06","2014-04-24 12:00:06"]}');
echo "Result: " . $obj->a;

Result: 14
```

This worked just fine in PHP Versions 5.3, 5.4, 5.5